# Reduzir o numero de arrays

Tags: javascript, html

Eu queria reduzir o numero de arrays e tentei desta maneira o problema é que eu acho que falta alguma coisa pois nao está a ler as informações dentro do json.

```html
<select id="myselect" class="classa" onchange="change_myselect(this.value)">
            
            <option value="">Faixa etária</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaA">0 a 17 anos</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaB">18 a 25 anos</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaC">26 a 35 anos</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaD">36 ou mais</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaE">Desconhecido</option>
        </select>

        <br> <br>

        <select id="myselect2" class="classb" onchange="change_myselect(this.value)">
            <option class="opcoes" value="">Sexo:</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaF">Masculino</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaG">Feminino</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaH">Desconhecido</option>
        </select>

        <br> <br>
        
        <select id="myselect3" class="classc" onchange="change_myselect(this.value)">
            <option class="opcoes" value="">Recurso a arma:</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaI">Sim</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaJ">Não</option>
            <option class="opcoes" value="faixaK">Desconhecido</option> 
        </select>
        
        <p id="demoA"></p>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function change_myselect(value) {

            $.getJSON("dados.json", function(json) {
            
             var faixas = { };
             var genero = { };
             var armas = { };
             
             for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                    if (faixas[json[i].Faixa] == undefined) {
                        faixas[json[i].Faixa] = ["FaixaA"];
                        faixas[json[i].Faixa] = ["FaixaB"];
                        faixas[json[i].Faixa] = ["FaixaC"];
                        faixas[json[i].Faixa] = ["FaixaD"];
                        faixas[json[i].Faixa] = ["FaixaE"];
                    }

                        faixas[json[i].Faixa].push(json[i].Nome + " " + json[i].Idade + " " + json[i].Localidade);

                    if (genero[json[i].Sexo] == undefined) {
                        genero[json[i].Sexo] = ["Masc"];
                        genero[json[i].Sexo] = ["Fem"];
                        genero[json[i].Sexo] = ["Desconhecido"];
                    }

                        genero[json[i].Sexo].push(json[i].Nome + " " + json[i].Idade + " " + json[i].Localidade);

                    if (armas[json[i].RecursoArma] == undefined) {
                        armas[json[i].RecursoArma] = ["Sim"];
                        armas[json[i].RecursoArma] = ["Não"];
                        armas[json[i].RecursoArma] = ["Desconhecido"];
                    }
                        
                        armas[json[i].RecursoArma].push(json[i].Nome + " " + json[i].Idade + " " + json[i].Localidade);

                }
                
                 if($('#myselect').val() == "faixaA"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = faixas;
                }

                if($('#myselect').val() == "faixaB"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = faixas;
                }

                if($('#myselect').val() == "faixaC"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = faixas;
                }

                if($('#myselect').val() == "faixaD"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = faixas;
                }

                if($('#myselect').val() == "faixaE"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = faixas;
                }

                if($('#myselect2').val() == "faixaF"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = genero;
                }

                if($('#myselect2').val() == "faixaG"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = genero;
                }

                if($('#myselect2').val() == "faixaH"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = genero;
                }

                if($('#myselect3').val() == "faixaI"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = armas;
                }

                if($('#myselect3').val() == "faixaJ"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = armas;
                }

                if($('#myselect3').val() == "faixaK"){
                    document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = armas;
                }

</script>
```

No VS code diz que não tem erros mas o codigo nao lê os dados no json que estao noutro ficheiro e aparece assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Mas se você tem faixas diferentes precisa armazenador os valores separados, mas é possível reduzir o número de arrays e simplificar um pouco assim:

```
var faixas = { };

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
   if (faixas[json[i].Faixa] == undefined) {
      faixas[json[i].Faixa] = [];
   }

   faixas[json[i].Faixa].push(json[i].Nome + " " + json[i].Idade + " " + json[i].Localidade);
}
```

Basicamente foi criado um objeto que é um dicionário, onde a chave é o nome da faixa. Primeiro verifica se existe um item com a chave, senão cria um vazio, depois faz o `push`.

Para usar depois basta usar a mesma chave, por exemplo:

```
var faixaA = faixas["faixaA"];
```

Comment: eu ja alterei tudo mas agora em vez de aparecer os dados do json aparece "[object Object]"

Comment: pode colocar o código como ficou na pergunta?